# [BodyPix]A memory leak coused while running segmentPerson in Firefox

Tags: tensorflow.js

I want to distinguish between the person and the background from the webcam video in Firefox.
However, running segmentPerson in a loop causes a memory leak.
For example, even on the BodyPix demo site, a memory leak occurs in Firefox.

https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/body-pix/index.html

So I want to run segmentPerson without memory leak in Firefox, is there a workaround?

TensorFlow.js version:
1.2

Bodypix version:
2.0.0

Firefox version: 76.0.1 (64 bit)

OS: Windows 10

Thanks

Comment: If you are sure that there is a memory leak on the official code, you can file an issue on github for that giving more details on the memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I asked the same question on github, but they answered, "this sort of question is better suited for StackOverflow".

I'm beginner to github and StackOverflow so I don't really know which one is right for me, but I think the official code is causing the memory leak.

The status of the question on github is "closed", but I'll try again.

Comment: Could you maybe add to the question why you think that there is a memory leak and what particular part of the code is causing it ? Additionnally you can also indicate the different output when using another browser

Comment: Thank you very much.
I am very grateful to you for your advice.
I'll ask the question again on github with more info and a reason I think I'm having a memory leak.

Comment: What kind of requirements are necessary to run bodyPix in real time? I tried their demo: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/body-pix/index.html and it annihilates my iPhone 6S safari running iOS 13.4.1. It's so choppy that it's essentially not usable. Has anyone run bodyPix real time on a mobile phone browser?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was also facing this issue and looked into this [test-file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/646992fd7ab8237c0dc908f2526301414b417c95/body-segmentation/src/selfie_segmentation_tfjs/tfjs_test.ts#L41) and it seems you need to do some stuff in the post to dispose of the tensors.

```
const segmentation = await detector.segmentPeople(input);
(await segmentation[0].mask.toTensor()).dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you SO SO MUCH. I thought I was going crazy. I was attempting to use Mediapipe Selfie Segmentation with tfjs-webgl backend and the memory leak was insane - even on the official demos! Adding this one line solved it!

Comment: this guy deserves a monument for digging through the test code and save me and the last guy and the next guy!!